# How can I route traffic between an OVS port and a physical interface on a Linux box?

Tags: sdn

I'm using OpenVSwitch as my networking layer for KVM virtual machines. I have a main bridge, and each VM has a tap on the bridge. I also have an internal tap on the host machine that's on the same VLAN as the VM taps. I can communicate between the host and the VMs just fine, but I'm having a hard time figuring out how I can use the host to route VM traffic out to the Internet via a physical interface.

Here's my OVS configuration...

```
foo@bar# ovs-vsctl show
b9d8798d-5a95-4d96-8df4-690ae9c8bae5
    Bridge br0   
        Port br0  
            Interface br0
                type: internal
        Port "br0_tap0"
            tag: 100     
            Interface "br0_tap0"
                type: internal
        Port "br0_tap1"
            tag: 100     
            Interface "br0_tap1"
        Port "br0_tap2"
            tag: 100     
            Interface "br0_tap2"
    ovs_version: "2.3.1"
```

And here's my interface configuration...

```
foo@bar# ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 3c:07:54:0e:9c:16 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.10/24 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 2601:140:8000:508b:3e07:54ff:fe0e:9c16/64 scope global mngtmpaddr dynamic
       valid_lft 345514sec preferred_lft 345514sec
    inet6 fe80::3e07:54ff:fe0e:9c16/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: ovs-system: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default
    link/ether 36:3f:76:54:8c:1a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
135: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default    
    link/ether 8a:c6:9d:08:23:4d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::88c6:9dff:fe08:234d/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
136: br0_tap0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,PROMISC,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default
    link/ether 82:86:88:2c:6a:56 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.1/24 scope global mega_tap0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::8086:88ff:fe2c:6a56/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
137: br0_tap1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master ovs-system state UP group default qlen 500
    link/ether 8e:50:e5:4f:1d:60 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::8c50:e5ff:fe4f:1d60/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
138: br0_tap2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master ovs-system state UP group default qlen 500
    link/ether d2:a7:4e:68:51:4c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::d0a7:4eff:fe68:514c/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

`tap0` is the internal tap that gives the host an IP address in `VLAN 100` so I can communicate with the VMs connected to `tap1` and `tap2`. I turned on IP port forwarding on the host using `sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`.

The VM on `tap1` has an IP address of `192.168.0.10/24`. From that VM, I'm able to ping the other VM on `tap2`, the host's `tap0` interface, and the hosts `eth0` interface IP address. However, I cannot ping anything outside of the host. My VM has a default gateway of the host's `tap0` IP address.

Any ideas?

Comment: You should check David Mahler's Channel https://www.youtube.com/user/mahler711 for SDN, Very useful (I hope, you already knew ;-P)

Answer (score 0):

You can route or bridge the traffic to a physical interface.

To bridge just add the physical interface to the bridge.

```
# brctrl addif br0 eth0
or 
# ovs-vsctl add-port br0 eth0
```

The move the eth0 ip to the br0 port

```
# ifconfig eth0 0.0.0.0
# ifconfig br0 192.168.1.10/24
```

To route, you will have a different subnet for the VM's and the physical interface.  You also need a a route on the external network that routes traffic for the internal subnet to the external IP, probably added on a router.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Pieter. However, I'm not sure if this will work since I'm needing the physical interface to be on VLAN 100 like the VM ports (ie. tap0 and tap1) are... I can add the physical interface to the OVS bridge no problem, but I can't seem to put it on VLAN 100 without losing connectivity to my network outside the host.

Comment: @Bryan please give more details on the Vlan's you are using on the network side.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get things working this morning by also adding in some `iptables` rules to NAT traffic between my `br0_tap0` interface and my physical `eth0` interface.

If anyone has another way of doing it that doesn't involve IP forwarding or iptables I'd love to see it!

Comment: If you NAT you can't connect from outside to individual VM's

Comment: I'm not worried about connecting from the outside in. I'm only worried about the VMs being able to get out to the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

What about like Pieter said and adding eth0 to the bridge, then giving a tagged "internal" interface back to the OS:

```
# ovs-vsctl add-port br0 eth0
# ifconfig eth0 0.0.0.0
# ovs-vsctl add-port br0 vlan100 tag=100 vlan_mode=access -- set interface vlan100 type=internal
# ifconfig vlan100 192.168.1.10/24
```